# Add resources to System PATH

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

I have a Maven application that includes .bat files, for usage in Window's CLI.

I'm considering having my .exe export (using launch4j) to request admin permissions and copy the resources to a subfolder in Program Files, is this good practice or should I move them somewhere else? If it is, how could I add the folder's `/bin` path to the PATH environmental variable?

For more clarification, I want to do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14)) with java.

Comment: A few questions:

1. Are you building the maven application yourself or is it built by someone and you are merely consuming it? If you are just consuming what already exists, the entity (person/orgn) that created the application may have better ways of invoking the application as it is meant to be.. and if it is just about invoking, a curious question is why maven for sharing??
2. For what purposes do you want the /bin added to the ENV variables? Only at build time? This is what I meant when I said "as it is meant to be".

Comment: @VenkataRahulS 1. This is my maven project that I'm making myself.
2. I want /bin (wrote from ProgramFiles, if good practice) added to the PATH system variable, preferably permanent, but it can be temporary during runtime, so that the batch files in there can be run from a Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the maven exec plugin?

You can potentially execute any command using the exec plugin but specifically if you want to invoke your own Java program which is the output of your build, you can use the exec:java target. Instead of executing your jar, you can directly mention the main class of your application and also furnish it with vm arguments.

Detailed documentation is [here](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)

Please note that you can include the environment variables while invokign the exec target with the help of maven's own environment property access methods.

There is a lot more you can do with this plugin (create different run-modes using the configurations, run servers from within your project dependencies, redirect output to an error file (redirect the mvn output itself) and so on... Read the plugin documentation and try them all out..

Comment: That's not what I need; On run, inject a path into the PATH system variable like you would the manual way (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14))

Comment: Just add the path setting commands to a command file and call it from your exec:exec and then run your exec:java. Call both targets in the same mvn call

Comment: I want to inject them during RUNTIME, and then remove them AFTER runtime is finished, if possible. I'm also asking what the "path setting" commands are in java code / batch code.

Comment: Yes. Please try the exec:cmd and exec:java chaining I explained above. The first target calls a cmd file to set the variables and the second one invokes your JAR or mainClass

Comment: I know how the maven execute plugin works... I'm asking HOW to inject it to the SYSTEM PATH variable either while the app is running or permanently.

Comment: Again, create an assembly that meets your requirements (for resources folders, properties et al). Have a bin folder in that assembly and let it contain your command files to invoke the jar. Now, before invoking the java command, export all your paths. This entire set of instructions to set your path and the classpath and other requirements can be written to a batch file and the build will recreate the assembly including your commands everytime the final zip is built bu the assembly plugin.

Comment: Here is the assembly plugin doc: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Gradle has an excellent way to do this. Please see https://liviutudor.com/2016/02/17/gradle-customize-startup-scripts-for-java-applications/

Comment: I think you're misunderstading my usage; I want to add my .bat folders to the system path so I can invoke commands in the terminal, similar to how java adds java.exe nto the path. I don't want to inject it when the project is building. When the app is opened, crate a folder in Program Files with app data and such, or the user root. When it is finished, add the path to a System Environmental Variable (in this case, PATH).
The PATH variable will let me execute my batch scripts in the terminal (i.e. if I have a file named run.bat, I can do run with arguments). How do I do that?